# Is it possible to get the download link with sharing option from GDrive API in C#?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to upload files to GDrive and get the download link for all users that have the link. Currently I managed to [upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) and get the [download link](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/). But I don't know how to get the download link for all users. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit the permission of the file to make it accessble for all user.

- I have done the python version. C# will have the same implementation.
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
- Use the above link to create a project and download **client_secret.json**.
- Create a python file in the same location where the
  **client_secret.json** is located.
- Then use the code below to upload and create sharable link.

Code:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
gauth = GoogleAuth()
# Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
#if there is any error in clent_secret.json try downloading it again after enabling drive api
#now the drive is accessible through python

#Lets create a folder named 'New_folder' in gdrive
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title'   : 'New_folder',
                          'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"})
file1.Upload()
#it will create a folder in your drive 
#mimeType is an argument which specifies the type of file

#Now we have created a folder, lets see how to upload a file to the folder which we have created

#We need to obtain the Id of the folder which we have created in the previous steps 
folder_id = file1['id']

#lets upload an image to the folder
file2 = drive.CreateFile({'title':'filename.jpg',
                          'mimeType':'image/jpeg',
                          'parents': [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": folder_id}]
#In parents argument above we need to specify the folder ID of the folder to which it has to be uploaded.
#mimeType is different for each file type, which are available in the google api documentation.

#specify the local path with the quotes in the below line
file2.SetContentFile('/home/username/Downloads/image.jpg')
file2.Upload()

#SET PERMISSION
permission = file2.InsertPermission({
                            'type': 'anyone',
                            'value': 'anyone',
                            'role': 'reader'})

#SHARABLE LINK
link=file2['alternateLink']

#To use the image in Gsheet we need to modify the link as follows
link=file2['alternateLink']
link=link.split('?')[0]
link=link.split('/')[-2]
link='https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='+link
print link
```

Comment: This could use some more explanation and an example of how to do so.

Comment: I will try this when I have time and paste my solution if it works. Thanks ;)

Comment: I've put the whole thing I did on github. Just in case anyone else is interested, follow: https://github.com/SeppPenner/GoogleDriveExample

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) that Google Drive supports providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the `webViewLink` property.

Also, the Google Drive provides you a 3 ways to download a file.

> - Download a file — files.get with alt=media [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
> - Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

Just remember that when you use `webContentLink` in downloading the file, this is only available for files with binary content in Drive.

To get the direct download link for a Google Drive file, you can go to the Google Drive developers API references and use their **`“try it!”`** API explorer form for the [`get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) API call. In the `fileId` textbox, just paste the `file’s ID` and in the `fields` textbox, just place `webContentLink` then click **`“Execute”`**. Below under response, in the generated JSON, the direct link that you need is called `webContentLink` and looks something like this:

```
"webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0ByP7_A9vXm17TmRYcmNScnYzS1E&amp;export=download"
```

For more information, check this [thread](http://knowm.org/how-to-get-the-direct-download-link-for-a-google-drive-file/).

Comment: But this gives me a 403 forbidden... I want to do exactly the same like the "share with all" option in Google Drive... Do you by any chance know if this is possible?

Comment: So generating the link works (If I'm logged in, it works, too).  But I want to share the file with all users that have the link. Is this possible with C#?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the C# language. What can I suggest you is try to find some tutorials or Github in the internet that can help you with that. Once I found some link that can do what you want in C#, I will post it here.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, would be great, I already searched on the internet and didn't find anything :/