# Google Drive: Upload and get a link through Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a small startup that is growing a little now and I'm trying to optimize some processes.

Every day I upload manually more than 100 PDFs to Google Drive and after that, I create a link one by one (that can be sharable).

Is this possible to do through Python? I tried to find some information and I have a lot about uploading but not about getting a sharable link.

Comment: Yes this is quite possible using [PyDrive](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925649/is-it-possible-to-get-the-download-link-with-sharing-option-from-gdrive-api-in-c) for more.

Comment: Works perfectly!